In Ionic React, from web browser I can fetch data from api (Laravel), but from the android app it is showing error: 419 'csrf token mismatch'
I am doing login page on Ionic React. I'm using Laravel sanctum for authentication. When I run the Ionic App on chrome browser, I'm able to pass login data and get logged in and store token in localstorage. But on the Android app, everytime I try to login, it is showing error: 419 'csrf token mismatch'.

I have added my public domain in Sanctum Statefull domain
I have added my public domain in cors.php 'allowed_origins' and
Set 'supports_credentials' => true

I am using: Laravel Framework 10.48.10, Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 8.1.2,  @capacitor/android : 6.0.0
I have tried to login from Ionic Android using laravel sanctum.
I was expecting to get message either 'Login failed: login credentials incorrect' or 'Logged in successfully' then receive the token and save it in the localstorage.
I am getting error: 419 'csrf token mismatch'
